# Twitter integration and iOS5: semantic and parsing issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter

I was using some of Apple's example code to write the Twitter integration for my app.

However, I get a whopping amount of errors (mostly being Semantic and parse errors).

How can this be solved?

```
  -(IBAction)TWButton:(id)sender {
ACAccountStore *accountstore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
//Make sure to retrive twitter accounts
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountstore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[accountstore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) [{
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountstore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
    if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

            TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"]  parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[@"Tweeted from iBrowser" forKey:@"status"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

            [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

            [postRequest preformRequestWithHandeler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                [self preformSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displaytext:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
            }];

        }
    }];
}
 //Now lets see if we can actually tweet

 -(void)canTweetStatus {
     if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
         self.TWButton.enabled = YES
         self.TWButton.alpha = 1.0f;
     }else{
         self.TWButton.enabled = NO
         self.TWButton.alpha = 0.5f;
     }



}
```

[image]

Comment: It would probably be better if instead of using a screenshot you used the actual text from the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error I see is easy to get rid of.

Objective C convention is to make the first letters of each method name lower case.

Use `makeKeyAndVisible` in your AppDelegate.m

The other errors we'd probably need to see where (in your code) the errors are being thrown, not just what kind of errors.

Comment: @Micheal Thank you, but I still get the error "makeKeyAndVisible is not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'" and as for a better view of the errors, they can be found at: yfrog.com/klvqxrp

Comment: change that first error line to `if (granted) {` (removing the [ bracket there.

Comment: @Micheal Thank you :), do you have any advice for the other errors?

Comment: Take a look at the errors carefully and see if it's a spelling error or a unbalanced bracket or something else like that. You'll get the hang of Objective C in no time!

Comment: @Micheal, quick question, I constantly get the error "use of undeclared identifier postRequest". I get that with other variables that I have checked on to make sure I have declared them. Any ideas?

Comment: If the `postRequest` in your code is the same `postRequest that is throwing errors, then you need to declare your `TWRequest * postRequest` in a different way and in a class context, not locally like that.  If this isn't the problem, then we can get onto chat.stackoverflow.com and I can try to walk you through coming up with a solution.

Comment: @Micheal Sorry about wasting your time, a simple rewriting of a few blocks of code fixed up everything. However, I corrected my [self.MakeKeyAndVisible]; error by lowercasing the m but I still get: Property 'makeKeyAndVisible' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'. Any suggestions? Thank you so much for all your help! :)